# 'Fattest' polygons based on diameter and 'least width'

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

**Definitions:** The diameter of a convex region is the greatest distance between any pair of points in the region. The least width of a $2$D convex region can be defined as the least distance between any pair of parallel lines that touch the region. Let us refer to a polygon as 'fat' if the ratio between its diameter and least width (call this the 'thinness ratio') is low.

**General Question:** Given a general $n$, which $n$-gon is the fattest? For which values of $n$ (if at all) is the fattest n-gon a regular $n$-gon?

**2 Special cases:**
-For $n =3$, the equilateral triangle is the fattest. The thinness ratio is $2/\sqrt(3) \approx 1.15$.

-For $n = 4$, the square is not the fattest - its thinness ratio is $\sqrt{2}$. As pointed out by Yakov Baruch below, if we form a quad by adding a vertex arbitrarily close to one of the vertices of an equilateral triangle, its thinness ratio is only about $1.15$.

**Some Further Queries:** Thanks very much to Prof. O'Rourke for the pointer to Bezdek and Fodor's work (answer below) that answers just the above question.  One could ask a further question: Given values for area and perimeter, which convex shape (not necessarily polygonal) is the most/least fat?

For fixed $A$ and $P$ within a suitable range (from perimeter equal to that of circle of area $A$ to perimeter of a Reuleux triangle with area $A$), it appears that fatness is maximized by curves of constant width (https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-and-minimizing-diameter-ii.html). For $P$ values greater than this range, I don't know.

For specified $A$ and $P$, diameter is maximized by a 'convex lens' shape as given  in above linked page. But this shape does not seem to minimize fatness.

Comment: For $n=4$ an equilateral triangle seems to be fatter than the example given. Then also any non-degenerate quadrilateral close to it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Shall correct it!

Comment: Notice that in general the regular $(2n-1)$-agon beats the regular $(2n)$-agon. I suspect the odd regular polygons are optimal.

Answer (score 7):

The paper

> Audet, Charles, Pierre Hansen, and Frédéric Messine. "Extremal problems for convex polygons-an update."
> *J Global Optimization* 55 (2009): 1-16.
> [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-006-9065-5).

discusses this problem, which I believe is equivalent to your question:

> Find for all $n$ which convex polygon with unit diameter has the largest width.

They cite Bezdek and Fodor for these results:

(a) The maximum width satisfies $W_n \le \cos \frac{\pi}{2n}$ for $n \ge 3$ and equality holds
if $n$ has an odd divisor greater than $1$.

(b) If $n$ has an odd prime divisor then a polygon $V_n$ is extremal if and only if it is equilateral and is inscribed in a Reuleaux polygon of constant width $1$, so that the vertices of the Reuleaux polygon are also vertices of $V_n$.

(c) Results are also obtained for quadrilaterals: $W_4 = \sqrt{3}/2 \; (=W_3)$. Moreover, all extreme quadrilaterals have the property that three of their vertices form a regular triangle and the fourth vertex is contained in the Reuleaux triangle determined by the three vertices.

> A. Bezdek and F. Fodor, On convex polygons of maximal width, *Archiv der Mathematik*, Vol. 74, No. 1, pp. 75–80, 2000.